# What is the topology on the set of field orders

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology, fields, real-algebraic-geometry

*Inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344775/free-ordered-field) I was wondering whether there is a natural topology on the set of all orders on a field (that extend a given order on a subfield)?*

For example for the function field $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ there are the following examples of total orders:

1. The convention $X>q$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$;
2. the convention $0<X<1/n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$;
   the pullback of
3. the standard-order on the reals along an embedding $\mathbb{Q(X)}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ sending $X$ to any transcendental element;

   4. the pullback of the total order on the surreal numbers along an embedding.

I suspect that different embeddings in (4) still can give the same total order, but maybe all orders arise that way.

*Apart from the question how to classify these field orderings as a set, it seems interesting to ask how to topologize them.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The topology you are looking for is called the *Harrison topology*. If we denote the set of ordering of a field $F$ with $\mathrm{Sper}\,F$ (more on that in a moment), this is the subspace topology given by the embedding
$$\mathrm{sign}:\mathrm{Sper}\,F\to \prod_{x\in F^\times}\{+1,-1\}$$
sending an order to the collection of signs of the elements of $F^\times$. This identifies $\mathrm{Sper}\,F$ as a closed subset of that product, and hence as totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space. A basis of clopen sets is given by $U_x:=\{\le\mid x> 0\}$ for every $x\in F^\times$.

This is a special case of the construction of the *real spectrum* of a ring $A$. That is the collection of the ``partial orders'' of $A$, which are essentially couples $(p,\le)$ where $p\in\mathrm{Spec}\,A$ is a prime ideal and $\le$ is an order on the residue field $k(p)$. We can topologize it as the closed subspace of
$$\mathrm{sign}:\mathrm{Sper}\,A\to \prod_{x\in A}\{+1,0,-1\}$$
where $\{+1,0,-1\}$ has the coarsest topology such that $\{0\}$ is closed and $\{+1\}$ and $\{-1\}$ are open.

To give a concrete example, the points of $\mathrm{Sper}\,\mathbb{Q}(x)$ are of one of the following forms

- $a^+,a^-$ where $a$ is a real algebraic number. The order is given by $f\ge 0$ iff $f$ is non-negative in $(a,a+\epsilon)$, resp. $(a-\epsilon,a)$ for some $\epsilon>0$
- $r$ where $r$ is a trascendental real number. Here $f\ge0$ iff $f(r)\ge0$
- $+\infty,-\infty$. Here the order is given by $f\ge0$ iff $f$ is non-negative on $(M,\infty$), resp. $(-\infty,-M)$ for some $M>0$. Equivalently, this picks the sign of the leading coefficient (resp. $(-1)^{\deg f}$ times the sign of the leading coefficient).

These are all distinct, as one can easily show.

The topology of $\mathrm{Sper}\,\mathbb{Q}(x)$ has a basis of clopen subsets of the form $(a,b)$ where $a,b$ are either real algebraic numbers or $\pm\infty$. This is the set of orders $\ge$ such that $f\ge0$ if $f$ is non-negative on $(a,b)$. Note that $a^+\in (a,b)$, but $a^-\not\in(a,b)$.

There is a more comprehensive treatment of this, with more examples, in chapter 7 of

> *Bochnak, Jacek; Coste, Michel; Roy, Marie-Françoise*, Real algebraic geometry. Transl. from the French., Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 3. Folge. 36. Berlin: Springer. ix, 430 p. (1998). [ZBL0912.14023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0912.14023).

Comment: It seems as if at least for the upper example the set of all orders is ordered itself and  that there is a canonical quotient map identifying $a^\pm$ such that the quotient space is $[-\infty,\infty]$. This seems really similar to the setting where one takes the standard cantor set and identifies both endpoints of each removed interval and the quotient space is again a unit interval.

Comment: @HenrikRüping There is a naturally defined map from $\mathrm{Sper}\,\mathbb{Q}(x)$ to $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$, whose fibers are either $\{\pm 1\}$ or just a point depending if the target is algebraic or not. This can be generalized to a map from $\mathrm{Sper}\,F$ to the $\mathbb{R}$-points of the Zariski-Riemann space of $F$, and that's what you're seeing. The fiber over a point $(v,k(v)\to\mathbb{R})$ is given (noncanonically) by the set of homomorphisms from the valuation group of $v$ to $\{\pm1\}$.

Comment: Reference to Harrison topology: *Harrison, D. K. Finite and infinite primes for rings and fields. Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. No. 68, 1966, 62 pp.*

Comment: **The real spectrum!** As opposed to the *fake spectrum* which appears often in the liberal, left-wing preprint suppositories!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Take it up with whoever thought it was a good idea to call the unique complete ordered field the "real" numbers (not like those fake numbers like $i$)...

Comment: [Obligatory SMBC reference](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2010-09-27).